# How to measure resistance of resistance of gel electrolyte using multimeter

Tags: batteries, conductive, conductivity

How can I measure the resistance of a gel electrolyte using a multimeter?
I know the formula to measure the conductivity of a gel electrolyte is 
k = (1/R) * (d/a)

where k is the conductivity (S/cm), R is the resistance (of the electrolyte), d is the distance between the two electrodes, and a is the effective area of the electrodes.

I wanted to measure the conductivity of the gel electrolyte with just a multimeter. Since this is a gel electrolyte, I was thinking to substitute the thickness of the gel electrolyte as d and substitute the area of the gel electrolyte as a. (I know the area (a) has to be that of the electrodes, but I want to measure the conductivity of the gel electrolyte without the electrodes). So now all that remains is the resistance of the gel electrolyte. To do this can I just measure its resistance using a multimeter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would get a number but I'm not sure it would be a good one, due to possible potentials and polarization.

I think you'd be better to use mains or low-audio frequency AC with a series resistor and measure the AC voltage across the electrode vs. the total voltage, then you can easily calculate the AC resistance of the electrode.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6KXZB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Rx = \$\frac{\text R_S}{(\frac{\text VM2}{\text VM1} -1)}\$

Comment: "then you can easily calculate the AC resistance of the electrode." By his do you mean the resistance of the electrolyte. Like I know that you have to measure the conductivity of an electrolyte using two electrodes  (which are the same), but I wanted to measure the resistance of the electrolyte without the electrodes because I don't have an AC source at my disposal.

Comment: Do you know how I could make this low audio frequency AC?

Comment: You need to connect with it whether you're using AC or DC (as a multimeter uses).  Can't you find a function generator or a mains transformer or even use the sound card on your PC?

Comment: Yes, it will work with low audio frequency AC. Limited by the response of your multimeter (check the manual) but a few hundred Hz should be fine. Sound card would work.

Comment: I do not have a function generator or a mains transformer. So as you said, using a dc source as compared to an AC one would give incorrect results? Would the results be really off if I used a dc source or just a multimeter to check the resistively?

Comment: You can get some idea of what the error might be by measuring *voltage* before resistance (should be close to zero) and seeing if the apparent resistance measurement changes if you leave it connected for many seconds. If it doesn't change much, there is no voltage, and it reads the same when you reverse the probes it's probably reasonably close.

Comment: Ok, so if DC measurements are reasonably close, why is AC used instead? You mentioned polarization and possible potentials.

Comment: *If* is the key word above.

Comment: Ok got it. Until I don't get access to a function generator, can I just switch the AC source in your schematic above with a DC one? Thank you so much

Comment: Just try the multimeter directly and see if it works as discussed above (voltage, then ohms, then swap leads and ohms).

Comment: Ok got it, and then I can substitute the resistance value from my multimeter into this equation  k = (1/R) * (d/a)? Sorry, but what do you mean by reversing the probes?